# Make onClick event work for visually impaired

Tags: javascript, onclick, accessibility

I got a problem with a website that use onClick event to add items to the cart. The problem comes up to visually impaired users that cant use keybord to add the products.

I guess that bringin back the add function with a normal href="addtocard.php?id=1234" should solve the problem but on the SEO side this can effect other problems.

Is there any other way, maybe using events such as onkeypress, or that's totally related to the use of javascript? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would this affect SEO? Google will spider your site with javascript turned off so wouldn't ever hit an onclick event.

Comment: Its not me, i'm only write codes... this advice was given to me by a seo consultant :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having an addtoCart.php?ID=5 should not have a detrimental impact on your SEO.  Modern/top search engines will be smart enough to recognise what the function of that page is, and index it accordingly.

When designing sites, I forget the specific name of this type of design, but it is always best to build it upwards, that is add on the onclick/javascript functionality as an extra over the top of the base of your site, so that if users have any of these features disabled the site will still function perfectly, so that is something to consider when building your next site.

So I would recommend building the addtoCartPage.  I don't think it's as bad as you think it is.

Comment: it's called Progressive enhancement: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_Enhancement

Comment: Thanks!  Just forgot it, Luciano I recommend you read that link

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
<a href="javascript:addToCart(1234);">Add To Cart</a>
```

Or somethinkg like this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="addToCart(1234)">Add To Cart</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the other way around from what your SEO consultant said. Most visually impaired people prefer keyboards. It's mice they can't use so well. The name makes you think that onclick only works with a mouse, but in general, onclick works fine for the visually impaired/non-mouse users, since it is triggered with the Enter key as well as with a mouse click. See http://webaim.org/techniques/javascript/eventhandlers#onclick.

That's why using onkeypress for accessibility is [not a good idea](http://www.irs.gov/irm/part2/irm_02-025-005.html). Jeremy Keith flatly says, "[Beware of onkeypress](http://books.google.com/books?id=CcZnh7PUG3QC&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=onkeypress+accessibility&source=bl&ots=qbARgL8-2G&sig=CcOFBT-ZvFY_ABT5JaN78Yawk0Q&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YYxzT56MGO-r2AW8ha3vDg&ved=0CG8Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=onkeypress%20accessibility&f=false)" since even a Tab key could make it fire.

Besides progressive enhancement in general, you might try [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) in particular, which uses Javascript to rewrite links, and that means users without Javascript get regular HTML links. If Google can't follow your Javascript links, you do have an SEO problem.